# Java Glass Pane for WPF (C#.NET)

Tags: c#, wpf, glasspane

I am building a WPF application in C#.NET and I would like to grey out the window and display a StackPanel in the centre, if a condition is true, like the glass pane in Java. I will be selling my application so I would prefer not that have to ship another licence with it, and it really needs to be free.

Is there any code to let me do this?

Comment: I really don't understand why this question has been put on hold, especially when the question has been solved and is finished with now. I don't understand how I could have demonstrated any further understanding of the solution, etc. How should I reword the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply a `MonochromeEffect` from the [WPF Shader Effect Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/) whenever you popup a dialog:

When opening a dialog:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Effect = new MonochromeEffect() { FilterColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 90, 90, 90) };
```

When closing a dialog:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Effect = null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do believe that the Ms-PL license (the license for the library) requires you to package the licence with commercial software so I was a looking for a solution which doesn't have this requirement. Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: @Andy no I don't think so. I'm using that and never had any problems. Otherwise instead of the `MonochromeEffect`, just change that to a `BlurEffect` (built-into WPF).

Comment: Hmmm... If that isn't the case then I could just as easily use this library as it offers exactly what I want: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator but I want to make absolutely sure that this is the case before I go ahead and include it! But if I can't use that library due to licensing restrictions, `BlurEffect` is perfect. Thank you

Comment: @Andy don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it was useful to you =)

Comment: Marked as accepted! :) Thanks for the link to your question. So when you say a "commercial product" I guess you're selling the software that uses the library?

Comment: @Andy right. I create business applications with a twist =)

Comment: Sounds 'interesting'. Thanks for the help :)